# Cakephp:How can i reference to a field in another table while i have the primary key

Tags: cakephp

I want to print out the `programme_name` in my `programsubjects` controller, but currently I have only the `programme_code` from the programmes controller.

How can I make my drop down list to bring the `programme_name`?

My code:

```
  $list[]=$this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->
  find('list',array('fields'=> array('programme_code'),
  'conditions'=>array(' ProgrammeRequirementsSubject.subject_code'=>$s_code,
  'compulsory'=>'true'),
   'group' =>array('programme_code')));
```

Now my `programme_code` is a primary key for the programme model, so how can I make it bring the `programme_name` while I have the programme_code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the displayField model attribute to specify what's the field that you want to show as text on your ddl (by default the primary key will be the value). There are more details on the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)